# Facebook OpenGraph Story link to app on Facebook

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph, facebook-canvas

I am working on an game app contained in Facebook via the Canvas.  The game consists of several order-independent 'levels' that each correlate to an entry in a database.  Metaphorically, you can think of it as similar to hangman in that the game is the same each time but the content in different (in the case of hangman, that is the word being guessed).

When the user plays a level, I create a story via the OpenGraph API.  So say for example Bob plays level Alpha, and his friend Sue sees his feed story which says "Bob played Alpha in SomeGame."  I'd like a link in that story to take Sue directly to playing level "Alpha" in SomeGame, and *not* to the generic entry point in the game where the user can pick a level (i.e. what normally happens when you hit the Canvas URL).  It appears that you can use params, like this:

apps.facebook.com/somegame?level_id=1234,

and then in your Canvas URL endpoint you can redirect based on those params.  But is that the preferred way to handle this?

Also, if the story title in the Feed is "Bob played Alpha in SomeGame", I'd like the link on "Alpha" to take Sue to playing "Alpha", but as far as I can tell that link is generated by og:url in the object metadata, meaning it has to link to

www.somegame.com/level/:id, and not

apps.facebook.com/somegame?context_params=some_stuff.

But I really don't want people to visit

www.somegame.com/level/:id

directly - I'd like them to stay inside Facebook, and view it within the app hosted by Canvas.

I can get the behavior I want if I give

www.somegame.com/level/:id

a javascript redirect, which uses parameters for the level id:

(top.location.href="http://apps.facebook.com/somegame?level_id=1234)

However this seems like a hack, and I was hoping there is a cleaner way to do it, without a browser-driven redirect. Thanks!